# Pass type to generic function and compare

Tags: swift

Consider this simple example

```
func contains<T>(type t: T.Type) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<list.count {
        if list[i] is t { // compiler says: 't' is not a type
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The compiler responds with

```
't' is not a type
```

Since I cannot declare a static type and do a check with `is MyStaticType`, how can I accomplish this in Swift with generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if it's `T`:

```
if list[i] is T {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `t` is indeed not a type.  It's an instance of the type `Metatype`:

```
let x = NSString.self
// compiler error because the following is 
// always true but you get the idea...
x is NSString.Type
```

You just want to check against `T`, which is the actual type, but can use `T.Type` to drive the determination of what `T` is:

```
// genericised a bit, to make list an argument
func contains
  <S: SequenceType, T>
  (list: S, type t: T.Type) -> Bool {
    for element in list {
        if element is T {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

let a = ["a","b","c"]
contains(a, type: String.self)    // true
contains(a, type: NSString.self)  // true
contains(a, type: Int.self)       // false
contains(a, type: NSNumber.self)  // false

let b: [Any] = [1, 2 as NSNumber, "c" as NSString]
contains(b, type: String.self)    // true
contains(b, type: NSString.self)  // true
contains(b, type: Int.self)       // true
contains(b, type: NSNumber.self)  // true
```

Bear in mind though that `T` is still being determined statically at compile time, not dynamically.  So:

```
let c: NSObject = 1 as NSNumber
contains(a, type: c.dynamicType)
```

returns `true` *not* `false`, because it is checking for `NSObject` (because the type of the result of `c.dynamicType` is `NSObject.Type` not `NSNumber.Type`).