# How to define class type as param in func?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to define enclosure method,which can goto an view controller
like
  *`gotopage(currentController,TargetViewController,"targetidentify")`*

```
   class func gotoPage<T: UIViewController>(currentController:ViewController,targetControllerClass: T.Type,identify:String){
        var mTargetViewController:targetControllerClass  =  currentController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identify) as! targetControllerClass
        currentController.showViewController(mTargetViewController, sender: currentController)
    }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308975/how-to-pass-a-class-type-as-a-function-parameter) is another similar question I have referenced.
The question is  **`as! targetControllerClass`** maybe not correct.
and error while building: "targetControllerClass" is not a type.
[image]
How can I define this method with Class Type?

Comment: Why is this a generic? What is going to specify T?

Comment: Possible duplicate from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308975/how-to-pass-a-class-type-as-a-function-parameter). Might need to change <T> to <T: someProtocol> where the protocol exposes an init() method.

Comment: I've checked that question, but seems not correct.

Comment: What is `selfsender`? This is a `class` method correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711993/pass-type-to-generic-function-and-compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All view controllers will inherit from `UIViewController`, given that you can adjust your method as follows:

```
func gotoPage<T>(currentController: UIViewController, targetControllerClass: T.Type, identify: String) {
    var newController = currentController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identify) as! UIViewController
    if newController is T {
        currentController.showViewController(newController, sender: currentController)
    }
}
```

You can then call it as follows:

```
gotoPage(self, targetControllerClass: UIPageViewController.self, identify: "test")
```

However, the addition of generics isn't very beneficial here.

Comment: Strange  grammar with Generic. targetControllerClass seems is externalParameterName in here not localParameterName